# How to set a color for macros inside emacs?

Tags: emacs, colors

I would know if it is possible to set C/C++ macros to be a specific color when the files are opened in [emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_Area_Network).

Comment: Why do you link to the Wikipedia article for SANs with the label emacs?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `.emacs` startup file:

```
(require 'font-lock)

(defun my-c-and-c++-mode-hook ()
  "Added to c-mode-hook and c++-mode-hook.  This function runs when you visit
a C or C++ file."
  (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-constant-face "blue")
  (turn-on-font-lock))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c-and-c++-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-and-c++-mode-hook)
```

You can change the color "blue" to a RGB specification, such as "#f88", if you want to get a color that Emacs doesn't have a predefined name for.

Comment: Unfortunately, the face `font-lock-constant-face` applies to more than just macros.  Any numeric literal, such as `123` or `3.14`, will appear in that face also.

Comment: You could define your own custom face to use in the above code, like this: `(set-face-foreground (make-face 'my-macro-face) "blue")`.  Then change `font-lock-constant-face` above to `my-macro-face`.